# Prevent email from being sent using hook_mail?

Tags: 7, hooks, emails

I'm trying to implement an access check (a 'do-not-send' list query) just before emails are sent. 
I see how to modify the message, but how do I stop a message?.

```
HOOK_mail ($key, &$message, $params) {
   if (TRUE) {
      // -- Stop Message From Being Sent Here -- //
   }
}
```

Is `break;` adequate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the access check from [`hook_mail_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) instead of `hook_mail` (let it prepare the default message based on parameters, and alter it later) by something like:

```
function HOOK_mail_alter(&$message) {
  // can add additional check for particular mails here,
  // by checking the value in $message['id']
  if (TRUE) {
    $message['send'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

**Note:** You should clear the cache in order to make the changes effective.

Comment: In case someone is wondering, this still works for Drupal 8.